# sort function in algorithm returning an error

Tags: c++, sorting

i am new to c++. i am trying to sort an array using `algorithm` header file and using `sort` function. But i am getting the following error: 
`error: member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union`. Is there some syntax error

i am declaring and initializing the array by this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> ptr[i];
    }
```

and this is sort function:
`sort(ptr.begin(), ptr.end());`

edit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int* ptr = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> ptr[i];
    }
    sort(ptr.begin(), ptr.end());

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << ptr[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears that `ptr` is an array or a`int*`. If it is, `ptr.begin()` and `ptr.end()` are not correct. Please post a [mcve] so someone can help you resolve the problem.

Comment: really sorry, i intended to include that line but for some reason forgot. btw it is an array indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ptr.begin()` and `ptr.end()` are not correct.

`ptr` is of type `int*`. Pointers don't have member functions. You can use the following instead.

```
sort(ptr, ptr+n);
```

Lets' say `n` is 5. `ptr` points to the first element of an array of 5 `int`s.

```
ptr
|
v
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

When you use

```
sort(ptr, ptr+n);
```

You are asking the function to sort all the objects that start at `ptr` and end at `ptr+n`.

```
ptr                 ptr+n
|                   |
v                   v
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Please note that the element `ptr[n]` is not valid and `sort` will not try to access it. It will access `ptr[n-1]` at most.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that begin and end work with arrays.

Comment: @CeNiEi, you may use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` with arrays but they have to be arrays whose size is known at compile time, such as `int a[10]; ... sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));`. That wont work if you use dynamically allocated arrays like you have.

Comment: Ohhhhhh thanx very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use vector instead of native array. First you are trying to use pointer to int instead of object. Anyway I recommend you to read some book about STL first.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. Can you please recommend some good materials.

Comment: Classic, of course, is the "Effective STL" by Scott Meyers. From the modern, I, personally, like "C++17 STL Cookbook" by Jacek Galowicz.

Comment: Thnx very much!!